# How can I add an anonymous property to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an empty object: {}

I'd like to add properties to it. I don't want or need the properties to have keys.

How can I do this?

Comment: you might want to check out scopes and closures. you can in fact create private properties by not exposing their data to a reachable scope.

Answer (score 3):

Objects must have property names, otherwise you can't access the properties.

Just use an array instead:

```
var myObj = [
   'item', 
   'item2'
];
```

Now just use `myObj[0]`, `myObj[1]`, etc.

Comment: Noted. However, the challenge still exists: once that object exists, how to I create new anonymous properties on it?

Comment: `myObj.push('another property')`.